# How to Change Evolution's Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, evolution, keyboard-accelerators

How can I change the keyboard shortcuts in Evolution 3.32.0, running on Ubuntu 18.04? I haven't been able to change shortcuts for things like "archive message" and others.

Here's what I've tried so far, unsuccessfully

1. Search the manual at https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/
2. edit the `~/.config/evolution/accels` file while Evolution is not running
3. in dconf editor, set `can-change-accels` to `true`, hover over command, type new shortcut
4. Reviewed related questions on askubuntu and others

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what worked for me using Evolution 3.22.0, on Ubuntu 18.04, with gtk 3.22

It is important to do every one of these steps, in order, because, Evolution can quickly overwrite the keyboard shortcuts to default, when it opens or when it closes.

1. Make sure that Evolution is not running.
2. Open the file `~/.config/evolution/accels` with a text editor
3. Find the line for the command you want to edit, for example `Reply to All` which looks like:
   `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mail/mail-reply-all" "<Primary><Shift>r")`.
   Here the spaces are only for indentation, but the semicolon at the beginning of the line comments-out the line.
4. Remove the semicolon and make your change so that line might look now like, for example, `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mail/mail-reply-all" "<Super>r")`.
5. Make sure you save, and then close the file in your text editor.
6. Now, re-open Evolution and you should see that the keyboard shortcut for `Message->Reply to All` has changed.

Special thanks to the members of the [*evolution-list* support mailing list](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution#Online_Support) who helped me learn this.

Comment: The `accels` file seems a little cryptic.  How did you differentiate between, say, `/action-group-standard/mail-reply-all` and `/mail/mail-reply-all` for finding the exact command you wanted to edit?

Comment: It sure is cryptic. I think I just ignored anything that didn't make sense. Until something didn't work, that is, and then I tried anything that seemed to have a similar meaning. Couldn't find the file documented anywhere.

Comment: `dconf-editor` seems to provide an alternative means of editing settings for gnome applications such as evolution.

Comment: @mikemtnbikes I suggest posting the `dconf-editor` solution as a seperate answer, with some how-to steps. This answer is getting a bit old and this might be the better approach.

Comment: There's no `~/.config/evolution/accels` file. At least not with a 3.44.2 Evolution version. I also tried to search for the `gtk_accel_path` keyword in the entire `~/.config/evolution/` directory and there was no matches ‍♂️

Comment: Am also not sure, what the discussion about `dconf-editor` editing refers to. When I execute `dconf dump /org/gnome/evolution/` there's nothing related to shortcuts.

Comment: I see `~/.config/evolution/accels`  file in 3.44.4, and editing it per this answer works.